# How to Print Entries from Database in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have some separate entries saved in a database (they are called "Pastes"). For each of these entries, I have a randomly generated string that is saved into a field called `generated_url` which I can then enter into the address bar to access details tied to that specific entry. Going to projectname.com/jF7Fwr will print all details tied to the entry that has `jF7Fwr` as the `generated_url`.

My issue is that while it correctly redirects to the page, I am not getting any of the details printed and I'm not sure why.

Here is the relevant portion of my `views.py`.

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.poster = request.user
            post.content = form2.cleaned_data.get('content')
            post.title = form2.cleaned_data.get('title')
            post.syntax = form2.cleaned_data.get('syntax')
            post.public = form2.cleaned_data.get('public')
            rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand):
                rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            post.generated_url = rand
            form2.save()
            context = {
                "poster_name": post.poster,
                "paste_contents": post.content,
                "paste_title": post.title,
                "paste_syntax": post.syntax,
                "paste_visible": post.public
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details', args=(post.generated_url,)))
    else:
        form2 = PostForm()

    return render(request, "home.html", {'form2': form2})

def detail_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "paste_detail.html", {})
```

And here is my `details.html` page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>Content of post:</p>
I AM REDIRECTED

<h1>Name of post: {{ post.title }}</h1>

<p>Content of post:</p>

<p>{{post.content|linebreaks}}</p>
<p>{{ poster_name }}
{{ paste_contents }}
{{ paste_title }}
{{ paste_syntax }}
{{ paste_visible }}</p>
<!--<form action="/{{post.generated_url}}/delete" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>-->
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT:

Should my `detail_view` be something like this?

```
def detail_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form2 = PostForm(request.POST)
    post = form2.save(commit=False)
    post.poster = request.user
    post.content = form2.cleaned_data.get('content')
    post.syntax = form2.cleaned_data.get('syntax')
    post.public = form2.cleaned_data.get('public')
    rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
    while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand):
        rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
    post.generated_url = rand
    post.save()
    context = {
        "poster_name": post.poster,
        "paste_contents": post.content,
        "paste_title": post.title,
        "paste_syntax": post.syntax,
        "paste_visible": post.public
    }
    return render(request, "paste_detail.html", context)
```

I'm just a bit confused on how the scope of variables are supposed to carry from each `def`.

Comment: Where's your details view?

Comment: @KlausD. I've edited my post. I believe my issue lays within that view, but I'm not sure where

Comment: About the scope: it is not transferred beween views since they are different HTTP request. To bring an information from one view to an other you have to use a form, a query string in the URL or another information embedded in the URL. This BTW also counts for the location URL of a redirect. Also there are sessions and cookies but that might be something to learn later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `detail_view` uses an empty context (`{}`), while the `context` variable in the `home_view` is unused. Fill the context in the details view like in the home view and it will work. For that you will have to retrieve the post from the database.

Remember that a redirect makes the client do a new request and the context is lost between the requests.

Comment: I was thinking to do that, but if I filled in the context for `detail_view` like I did in `home_view` wouldn't it not work due to `post` being within the scope of `home_view` ?

I understand your logic, it's just the actual implementation that is evading my brain.

Comment: As edited above, you will have to retrieve the object from the database again.

Comment: It may just be my brain being tired, but I'm not sure how to go about what you're saying. Please check OP for my edited question